# mysql is not returning any Row

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

I am writing the following code in my PHP program, but mysql is not returning any row. Kindly check and help to find out the mistakes in the following code.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    <?php


    //$query2= "SELECT * FROM `email` where `id` ='".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'" ;

        //$query2= "SELECT * FROM `email` where `id` ='".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'" ;
        $query= "SELECT * FROM `email` where `id` =' ".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'" ;

            $query_run2= mysql_query($query);   
            $query_num_rows= mysql_num_rows($query_run2);

                if ($query_num_rows==0) {
                    echo "Invalid Query";

                }
                    else {

                        $query_result = mysql_result ($query_run2, 0, 'name');

                        echo "Welcome" ;

                        echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
    }

?>
```

It is giving me the following Output.

`Log out
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in F:\xampp\htdocs\Email_address\welcome.php on line 20
Invalid Query`

Thanks,
Taha

Comment: mysql_query() takes 2 parameters, the second being a link_identifier.  More than likely, it's returning FALSE (which is not a valid resource) since you're probably not connecting to a mysql database using mysql_connect().  Check the return value of mysql_query() for FALSE and look at mysql_error().  Also, make sure you're connecting with mysql_connect() somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute your query and you cannot quote field / table names like that:

```
$query2= "SELECT * FROM 'email' where 'id' ='".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'" ;
```

should be:

```
$query2= "SELECT * FROM `email` where `id` ='".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'" ;
```

Note that the backticks are only necessary for reserved words in mysql and table and field names with spaces.

You should also not be using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions but PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: I have update my program, but still its giving me the same error message. `Log out
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in F:\xampp\htdocs\Email_address\welcome.php on line 20
Invalid Query`

Comment: @Taha Kirmani Have you actually connected to your database?

Answer (score 1):

you need to execute the query before you can grab the rows:

```
$query_run2 = mysql_query($query2);
```

you also need to connect to a database before you can run a query:

```
$con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVERNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD); 
$dbLink = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

$query_run2 = mysql_query($query2, $dbLink);
```

if you are using these mysql function, as opposed to switching to PDO, don't forget to close your database connection afterwards:

```
mysql_close($con);
```

If at all possible, I would strongly suggest switching to use PDO instead, here is some useful info if you do decide to go in that direction and set it up on your web server:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute your query:

```
$query_run2= mysql_query($query2);
```

Comment: The query has also another potential problem: There is a space before `".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'"`

Answer (score 0):

Try these :

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM `email` where `id` =' ".$_SESSION['user_id']. "'" ;
$rs = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: No change in the result :( . I have update the new code above .

Comment: First check your database connection.If it is ok then check the session value is empty or not.